# Magento 1.9 all admin extension changes not showing up

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, code-migration

`app/code/local` extension php file changes not reflected in admin panel
templete phtml file working well

**DEMO Site**-

[image]

**New Site (Not reflected)**-

[image]

Comment: compare the module files of both sites. some files of your module has not been updated.

Comment: Have you clear cache? If compilation is on then disable

Answer (score 0):

If the files on your demo site are **identical** to the ones on your live site:

1. Disable compiler
2. Flush Cache
3. Log out and back in

If the changes still don't show and you are convinced that there is difference in the files and no caching anywhere, then it might be that you have a config setting (this appears to be a custom model) that's different on your test/live site.